# Hacer un anotador de tenis con jquery o javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

estoy haciendo un app para seguir el puntaje de un partido de tenis, estoy teniendo problemas con el anotador, ya defini dos arrays en los que le di el valor de los puntos de tenis, y una variable para que recorra estos array, mi problema es como hacer para cuando el primer array este en la última posición y la variable del segundo array sume, el primer array vuelva a la posición anterior.

Dejo el código de ejemplo saludos.

```js
//función para sumar puntos en el anotador
            var puntaje=[0,15,30,40,"A"];
            var puntaje2=[0,15,30,40,"A"];
            var i = 0;
            var r = 0;
            
            console.log("i vale " + i);
            console.log("r vale " + r);
            $$("#suma1").click(function(){
                   
                   $$("#m1").val(puntaje[i]);
                   i++;
            
            if(puntaje[i] === "A" && puntaje2[r] === 40 ){
                
                if(r++){
                    
                    $$("#m1").val(puntaje[3]);
                    i= 3;
                    r= 3;
                }
    
            }

                   
            });
            
            $$("#suma2").click(function(){
                   
                   $$("#m2").val(puntaje2[r]);
                   r++;
            
            if(puntaje[i] === 40 && puntaje2[r] === "A" ){
                   
                   if(i++){
                        
                     $$("#m2").val(puntaje2[3]);
                     r=3;
                     i=3;
                    }
                    
                }
            });
```

```html
<div  class="marcador1">
            
                <input type="button" value="+" id="suma1" />
                <input type="text" id="m1" disabled />       
                <input type="button" value="-" id="resta1" />        
            </div>    
            
            <div  class="marcador2">
            
                <input type="button" value="+" id="suma2" />
                <input type="text" id="m2" disabled/>       
                <input type="button" value="-" id="resta2" />        
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que debes tener en cuenta cuando sumas un punto al marcador son tres posibles situaciones:

1. Un tenista vence un juego al hacer punto teniendo ventaja o al sumar
   un punto teniendo 40 y el contrincante 30 o menos.
2. Un tenista iguala la ventaja de un contrincante, retornando el marcador a 40-40.
3. Un tenista suma un punto.

De este modo, podrás gestionar qué hacer en cada ocasión.

En lo que se refiere propiamente al código, yo te haría dos recomendaciones:

- No te hace falta crear dos arrays de puntaje exactamente iguales. Ten en cuenta que lo que determina el puntaje son los valores de i y r. Podrías hacer exactamente lo mismo con un único array de puntajes.
- Lo ideal sería que al iniciar el script, el marcador estuviese ya 0-0 y no tuvieses que hacer clic en ambos puntajes para que se pusiesen a cero.

Así pues, el código que yo propondría en base a lo que tienes es esto:

```js
// Array donde se definen los puntajes
        var puntajes = [0, 15, 30, 40, 'A'];
  
  // Definiciones de los puntos de ambos jugadores
        var i = 0;
        var r = 0;
        
  // Log
        console.log("i vale " + i);
        console.log("r vale " + r);

  // Función para imprimir por pantalla los puntos de cada jugador
  function definirPuntaje() {
   $("#m1").val(puntajes[i]);
   $("#m2").val(puntajes[r]);
  }
  
  // Definir el puntaje al iniciar el script
  definirPuntaje();

  // Al añadir un punto al primer jugador
  $('#suma1').click(function() {
   
   if (i === 4 || (i === 3 && r < 3)) { // Situación 1: Si i vale 4 ('A') o i vale 3 (40) y r vale 2 (30) o menos, suma otro tanto, se termina el juego y se resetea el marcador...
    i = 0;
    r = 0;

    // Aquí dentro podrías incluir código para calcular los juegos y sets que lleva cada uno...
   } else if (i === 3 && r === 4) { // Situación 2: Si i vale 3 (40) y r vale 4 ('A') se vuelve a 40-40...
    i = 3;
    r = 3;
   } else { // Situación 3: Si no, se suma un punto al primer jugador...
    i++;
   }
   
   // Actualiza el resultado en función de los valores dados a i y r
   definirPuntaje();
        });

  // Al añadir un punto al segundo jugador
  $('#suma2').click(function() {
   if (r === 4 || (i < 3 && r === 3)) { // Situación 1: Si r vale 4 ('A') o i vale 2 (30) o menos y r vale 3 (40), suma otro tanto, se termina el juego y se resetea el marcador...
    i = 0;
    r = 0;

    // Aquí dentro podrías incluir código para calcular los juegos y sets que lleva cada uno...
   } else if (i === 4 && r === 3) { // Situación 2: Si i vale 4 ('A') y r vale 3 (40) se vuelve a 40-40...
    i = 3;
    r = 3;
   } else { // Situación 3: Si no, se suma un punto al segundo jugador...
    r++;
   }
   
   // Actualiza el resultado en función de los valores dados a i y r
   definirPuntaje();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="marcador1">
            
                <input type="button" value="+" id="suma1" />
                <input type="text" id="m1" disabled />       
                <input type="button" value="-" id="resta1" />        
            </div>    
            
            <div  class="marcador2">
            
                <input type="button" value="+" id="suma2" />
                <input type="text" id="m2" disabled/>       
                <input type="button" value="-" id="resta2" />        
            </div>
```